# Nim-like game with splitting heaps

Tags: recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

The motivation for this question came from a game introduced in a math(s) class, and so I thought it would be interesting to see if one could develop a winning strategy.

---

Let $S$ be a multiset $[a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n]$, with $ a_i\in\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$. A game is played on $S$ where two players take turns to play single moves where a move consists of the following:

> Replace an element $a\in S$ with $b,c\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $b+c<a$.

The last player to (be able to) make a (legal) move loses the game, i.e: s/he leaves each element of $S$ as zero.

This can be though of (and indeed was originally presented to me) as a misère Nim-like game where the elements of $S$ indicate the inital number of objects in  $n$ heaps, and, where in normal Nim a move consists of removing some number of objects from the *end* of a heap, instead in this game you can remove a contiguous run of objects from *anywhere in the heap*, potentially separating the heap into two separate, non-empty heaps.

---

Given the simplicity, I imagine there exists a winning strategy, for the first or second player depending on the initial $S$. However, I have never studied games mathematically, and don't really how to go about development of a winning strategy - this is my first point of enquiry. The second (or maybe zeroth) being: is this equivalent to an existing (well-understood?) mathematical game?

After some intial analysis of my own, I determined $[1,1,1]$, $[2,2]$, and  $[1,1,2,2]$ is won by the second player, and thus $[1,2,5]$ is won by the first player.

Comment: This would be the octal game $0.\dot7$.  Surprisingly, a first glance through the literature doesn't reveal any information about it.  I can't imagine why there wouldn't be, as it's simple enough that you would think it would be named after someone by now.

Comment: $[2,2]$ (like any "symmetric" position) should be a win for the second player by simply stealing the first player's strategy.  So $[1,2,X]$ is a win for the first player whenever $X>3$ by reducing the position to $[1,1,2,2]$.

Comment: Yes - sorry I mis-interpreted my notes: let me correct

Comment: @MatthewDaly you expect a solution... though none has been found?

Comment: Some octal games have complete solutions and others with equally clear rules don't.  I wouldn't venture a guess in this case.

Comment: @Matthew Actually, it's so simple it's not worth naming. The ability to split heaps doesn't make best play any different from Nim, either in misere or normal play.

Comment: @MarkS. I wouldn't mind reading that!  I don't think it's so trivial as to be uninteresting, and I don't recall the game coming up in Winning Ways (even though they covered trivial extensions of Nim).  It's hard for me to Google for, but if someone hasn't published an analysis of $0.\dot7$ showing that breaking into heaps was an irrelevant move for the best player in a recreational math journal, you should go for it!

Comment: @Matthew I don't think it's worth a journal article, but I found [my MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/224653/28209) giving a little detail.

Answer (score 2):

I think a player wins if they leave  a position consisting of either an odd number of 1s  or numbers, not all 1s, with zero nim sum.

**Proof** If left such a position with zero nim sum but not all 1s then your move will leave  a position with not all 1s and non-zero nim sum.

If left a position with not all 1s and non-zero nim sum then make the nim sum zero unless the position consists of 1s apart from one number. In that case reduce the larger number to zero/one to make the nim sum non-zero.